# Triangle Screw & Double Sided Eyes?

Tags: fasteners

I have a system of what appears to be a triangle screw (Or an eye screw bent into the shape of a triangle) and a double sided eye hook with some kind of washer on it. I couldn't find any references to it anywhere I searched. What kind of fasteners are these?
[image: Unknown Fasteners]
[image: Unknown Fasteners]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a [swing hook with bearing](http://www.stanleyhardware.com/detail/cd8375-galvanized-swing-hooks-with-bearing-s752-000) or [swing hangers](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Big-Backyard-Swing-Hangers-A24508/205853172).

[image: Swing hook with bearing]